# In Yosemite what does the indicator that looks like a scroll bar mean at the bottom of the desktop?

Tags: icon, macos

I've noticed that at the bottom of my desktop Yosemite has started displaying a strange sort of indicator - it looks like a horizontal scroll bar, it's a thin grey rectangle with rounded ends.

If I use large dock icons it overlaps with the dock itself, if I shrink the dock you can see that it is unrelated to the dock.

And no, it's not part of my wallpaper!

[image: Mystery grey rectangular icon on Yosemite desktop]

Comment: That is indeed the scroll bar. Do you have any applications that put a small window on your desktop? (For example, Bowtie places iTunes controls in a small window on the desktop.)

Comment: Good suggestion but not that I can see - closed every application, menu item app, desktop widget and even flushed out some unused preference panes - still there.

Comment: Have you upgraded to 10.10.1 ?

Comment: Yes I have actually - only noticed it after the upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug, not some sort of meaningful indicator as I first thought.

After quitting every application and restarting it's now gone away!